# Install from source hangs on 'pcl'

Tags: pcl, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Attempting to install from source. Following the directions for installing groovy from source. (generic source installation)
OS: 64 bit Ubuntu - Quantal

Chose Desktop install (Recommended) core packages.

I have gotten as far as the step that says...
Invoke catkin_make_isolated:

```
$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

Everything is working through package 144 of 153, but when it gets to pcl it errors out.

error message follows.

---

```
==> Processing plain cmake package: 'pcl'
==> Building with env: '/home/brian/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/brian/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'
==> make -j2 -l2 in '/home/brian/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl'
[  0%] Built target pcl_octree
[  0%] Built target pcl_io_ply
[  1%] Built target pcl_pcd_convert_NaN_nan
[  2%] Built target pcl_ply2obj
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libpcl_common.so
[  2%] Built target pcl_ply2ply
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsensor_msgs
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lroscpp_serialization
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrosconsole
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrostime
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libpcl_common.so.1.6.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [common/CMakeFiles/pcl_common.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Scanning dependencies of target pcl_ply2raw
[  3%] Building CXX object io/tools/ply/CMakeFiles/pcl_ply2raw.dir/ply2raw.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/pcl_ply2raw
[  3%] Built target pcl_ply2raw
make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'pcl': 
  Command '/home/brian/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> /home/brian/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2
```

---

I have tried to use option --force-cmake, and a few other things, but I have made no progress. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53645/install-from-source-hangs-on-%27pcl%27/) by [walkerbrianpatrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/4078/walkerbrianpatrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-01-29

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/53401/error-when-compiling-pcl-for-ros-groovy-install-from-source-on-ubuntu-12041/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1